# How to make a current source that supply constant current independent of a voltage power supply?

Tags: led-driver, constant-current

I want to design the simplest possible circuit that drives an LED. The LED must load the same amount of current whatever the voltage is at the input, between 5 and 9 V. The current could be 10 mA. I assume that must be a certain constant current source? Or maybe a window comparator?

Comment: Simplest possible would be a single JFET with gate-source shorted or a constant current diode.

Comment: How much accuracy do you need in the 10mA current?

Comment: Yes, a constant current source and no, not a window comparator.

Comment: You just need a voltage source that's higher than your LED Vf. For example if Vf = 2.5V for 10mA, then a 3.3V source with an 80 Ohm resistor would give you 10mA. You can create the voltage reference with a cheap LDO regulator or even a zener diode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. JFET is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be an Nexperia NCR401T as long as you can accept a maximum Vf of your LED being limited to 5 (minimum input)-1.4 (dropout) = 3.6 V.

A three terminal device but no external components needed.

[image]

[Datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/NCR401T.pdf)

Another suggestion would be a single JFET, which you need to pick (Perhaps hand-pick if your tolerance is too narrow) for your 10 mA.
[image]

Going up to two components, you get a little bit more refined solution if you add a resistor so you can adjust your JFET solution to get your desired current.

[image]

Comment: FET solution does the job and it's simplest. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If I assume that the LED has a maximum forward voltage of 3.2V then there is 1.8V to work with, with minimum input voltage of 5.0V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVNgPo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

The current changes a bit with input voltage (and with temperature) but not too bad for an LED.

Comment: very good and tested. Thanks.